# How to extract data from csv file with modification to data

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, csv

For eg i have a file called test.csv containing

```
emp1,dep1
emp2,dep2
emp3,dep1
emp4,dep3
emp5,dep2
```

expected output is

```
emp1 works in dep1
emp2 works in dep2
.
.
emp5 works in dep2
```

Answer (score 0):

Many tools can rearrange text, I would use `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{print $1" works in "$2}' file
```

eventually `sed`:

```
sed 's/,/ works in /' file
```